# Accessing value which is nested inside 2 keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, logic

Suppose I have the following dict:

```
L = {'A': {'root[1]': 'firstvalue', 'root[2]': 'secondvalue'}, 'B': {'root[3]': 'thirdvalue', 'root[4]': 'Fourthvalue'}}
```

How can I access the values of the keys `root[1], root[2], root[3], root[4]` (indexes of root[] is dynamic) in `Python 2.7`.

Comment: `L['A']['root[1]']`, `L['B']['root[3]']`, etc. If what you're asking is not that simple, you might want to add more explanation to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
>>> L = {'A': {'root[1]': 'firstvalue', 'root[2]': 'secondvalue'}, 'B': {'root[3]': 'thirdvalue', 'root[4]': 'Fourthvalue'}}
>>> L['A']['root[1]']
'firstvalue'
>>> L['A']['root[2]']
'secondvalue'
>>> L['B']['root[3]']
'thirdvalue'
>>> L['B']['root[4]']
'Fourthvalue'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the values from a dict nested inside the dict, i used the following step:

```
L = {'A': {'root[1]': 'firstvalue', 'root[2]': 'secondvalue'}, 'B': {'root[3]': 'thirdvalue', 'root[4]': 'Fourthvalue'}}

Solution:

F = {}
G = []
F = L.get("A", None)
F= {{'root[1]': 'firstvalue', 'root[2]': 'secondvalue'}}
for value in F.values():
    G.append(value)

Output:
G = ['firstvalue', 'secondvalue']
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for (key, value) in L.items():
    for (another_key, real_value) in value.items():
        print(another_key, real_value)
```